# iOS Universal Link App Store redirect

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have universal links working correctly, when the app is installed I see how the link opens the app, and when it's not installed opens the url in safari.

Actually what I would like to do is to redirect and go to the app store, so users can download the app directly.
Im going to include a redirect on the html file, because I know universal links don't support redirects a the http server config level (anyway I think this is for the manifest file only, apple-apps-site-association)

Anyone can confirm if this is the right way to do it, or the only way to do it? I don't like the idea to open safari first, load my html (with the redirect only) and then go to the store. Looks like there's no easier way to do it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're right: server-side redirects aren't allowed for the `apple-app-site-association` file. However, I believe once the user opens a Universal Link and (assuming the app is *not* installed) lands on the URL, all options are on the table (server-side, or otherwise).

If the page on the other end of your Universal Links URL contains an instant JS redirection to your app's App Store page, that should work just fine. Something like this:

```
window.location = 'itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imdb-movies-tv/id342792525'
```

But yes, no matter how you do it, Safari is still going to open. It'll flash past so quickly that the user likely won't even notice. Here's a real-time recording I just made of the [Branch.io](https://branch.io) deep linking service's demo app doing exactly this process:

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason for needing `setTimeout()` here? It doesn't seem like it would affect whether the redirection works.

Comment: You're right...not here. I was reusing part of another example and didn't simplify it enough 

Answer (score 12):

From here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

"When you support universal links, iOS 9 users can tap a link to your website and get seamlessly redirected to your installed app without going through Safari. If your app isn’t installed, tapping a link to your website opens your website in Safari."

You're not doing it wrong, that's just how they work.